# $f$ integrable implies $\left| f \right| $ in distinct intervals

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration

In an infinite interval this is not true. But in a finite interval is this true? Or at least in a closed interval?

$\textbf{EDITED:} $
Ok, suppose that $$
f:\left[ {a,b} \right] \to \mathbb{R}
$$
is Riemann integrable, is it true that the function $$
\left| f \right|:\left[ {a,b} \right] \to \mathbb{R}
$$
is Riemann integrable? Where $$
\left| f \right|
$$
denotes the function $$
\left| {f\left( x \right)} \right|
$$
this is my first question, the other is with other kinds of finite length intervals, like open intervals, or semi-opens intervals.

Comment: What you wrote is missing something... As it stands, it is not even grammatically correct :)

Comment: (And you should probably explain what exactly you mean by "integrable"...)

Comment: Riemann integrable

Comment: August, please add the information to the question itself. You *must* tell us what you want to know about $|f|$, as your title is surely missing the key part of the question!

Comment: How about $\int_1^{\infty} \frac{\sin(x)}{x}dx=\int_0^1\frac{\sin(\frac{1}{y})}{y}dy$?

Comment: @Jose27: that's not Riemann integrable, it only exists as an improper integral.

Comment: Can you also edit the title so that it makes sense?

Comment: @Robert Yes, it's not bounded, and so can't be Riemann integrable, but isn't the integral over infinite intervals also a kind of improper Riemann integral (this is what led me to believe that the question was open to improper examples).

Answer (score 1):

Yes (for Riemann integral on a closed interval $[a,b]$, not for improper Riemann integrals).  This is clear from the Lebesgue characterization of Riemann integrability, but you can also prove it using the fact that for any real interval $(c,d)$, $$\max_{x \in (c,d)} |f(x)| - \min_{x \in (c,d)} |f(x)| \le \max_{x \in (c,d)} f(x) - \min_{x \in (c,d)} f(x)$$

Comment: @Jose27  Wow thanks Robert Israel, Uhm I think that the equality of Jose27, it´s not correct